# Python - FileNotFoundError for existing file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, file-not-found

On my Windows 10 machine open() throws FileNotFoundError  for a file that does exist. The same file on a Windows 7 machine is found. What's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using python 32-bit on a 64-bit machine. Python x64 opens the file as expected.

Comment: 32-bit Python can access the real "System32" directory as "SysNative". This is a virtual directory that avoids the default redirection to "SysWOW64".